# Error with basic example C# SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, c#

I'm a little new to C# (okay... very new)

I've created an empty website in VS and added a Webforms page (Default.aspx).

I'm trying to use the SOAP API to get portfolio information from ExactTarget. I'm using [this example](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/retrieving-an-item-from-your-portfolio.html) from the documents.

I'm getting `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging.SoapClient'`

I've put the example code in my default.aspx.cs file, along with adding

```
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging;
```

Am I missing something obvious? Am I in the wrong place completely?

Answer (score 1):

I think they're talking about the [Exact Targer C# SDK](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp) (they could have mention it when using `SoapClient` name as it might seem a little bit confusing). After digging a while, it appears to have your [`SoapClient` implementation](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/blob/Dot9/FuelSDK-CSharp/ExactTargetSOAP.cs#L29894). So, remove your `Microsoft.Web.Services3` namespaces and use fuelSDK instead.